# Turing Machine language, Undecidable, reductions

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I have exam next week about automata theory, languages and computation. I struggle with reductions (Undecidability). For example for this two problems, and need to check first if the language is recursive, RE but no recursive or NOT-RE. After that to prove with reduction, okay for proving is easy I think, but to check what is language is my problem, please if someone can help me. For example how to decide in which category is this two languages?

1. $L = \{ \langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)|\neq 17 \}$
2. $L = \{ \langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)|= 17 \}$

Answer (score 2):

Before doing reductions, it is good to have some intuitions about decidability: that helps to find which reduction can succeed.

First, none of those two languages is recursive, because [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) states that nontrivial semantic properties are undecidable.

Second, since those languages are complement of each other, if one is RE, the other is not (otherwise, they would be decidable).

Another intuition that can help is reinterpreting $\langle M\rangle$, $L(M)$ and $L$: Turing machines are programs!

- $\langle M \rangle$ can be interpreted as the source code of a program;
- $L(M)$ can be seen as the set of inputs $x$ such that $M(x)$ terminates;
- $L_2 = \{\langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)| = 17\}$ is the set of programs that have $17$ inputs terminating.

Back to the problem:

- $L_1 = \{\langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)| \neq 17\}$ is the set of programs that don't have exactly $17$ terminating inputs. This cannot be decided, or even semi-decided, because you would need to test all inputs;
- $L_2$ is the set of programs that have exactly $17$ terminating inputs. While this could seem semi-decidable at first, because you could find those $17$ inputs, the problem is that you have to test all other inputs, to be sure that there are not any more that are terminating.

That would mean that none of the language is RE.

Now for a real reduction: I will reduce $L_{\in} = \{\langle \langle M\rangle, x\rangle\mid x\in L(M)\}$, which is a well-known non recursive language, to $L_2$. For convenience purposes, I will consider only integer inputs, but it is easy to work with any set of countable inputs.

From an input $\langle \langle M\rangle, x\rangle$ of $L_{\in}$, consider the following Turing machine $M'$, which on input $y$:

- simulates the computation of $M(x)$;
- if $M(x)$ accepts and $y\in \{1, 2, …, 17\}$, then $M'$ accepts $y$;
- otherwise, $M'$ rejects $y$.

Then $|L(M')| = 17$ if and only if $x\in L(M)$. This is a many-one reduction. Since $L_{\in}$ is not recursive, nor is $L_2$.

Also, since $L_{\in}\leqslant_m L_2$, that proves that $\overline{L_{\in}}\leqslant_m \overline{L_2} = L_1$. Since $\overline{L_{\in}}$ is not RE, nor is $L_1$ (that works because the reduction is many-one).

Now, a bit more difficult, we will prove that $L_2$ is not RE, by doing a many-one reduction from $L_{\in}$ to $L_1$ (which gives a many-one reduction from $\overline{L_{\in}}$ to $L_2$).

From an input $\langle \langle M\rangle, x\rangle$ of $L_{\in}$, consider the following Turing machine $M'$, which on input $y$:

- Simulates $y$ steps of the computation of $M(x)$;
- If $M$ does not accept $x$ at the $y^{\text{th}}$ step, and $y\in \{1, …, 17\}$, then $M'$ accepts $y$;
- If $M$ accepts $x$ at the $y^{\text{th}}$ step, and $y > 17$, then $M'$ accepts $y$;
- Otherwise, $M'$ rejects $y$.

Then:

- if $x\notin L(M)$, $M$ will never accept $x$ during the $y$ steps of computation, and $L(M') = \{1, …, 17\}$;
- conversely, if $x\in L(M)$, then:

  - if $M$ accepts $x$ in $k \leqslant 17$ steps, $L(M') = \{1, 2, …, k-1, k+1, …, 17\}$, so $|L(M')| < 17$;
  - if $M$ accepts $x$ in $k > 17$ steps, then $L(M') = \{1, 2, …, 17, k\}$, and $|L(M')| > 17$.

This is indeed a many-one reduction from $L_{\in}$ to $L_1$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. You explained me a lot, but I have some other questions, when exactly I use the Rice's theorem? Also for example, this language is RE, but not recursive, can you explain to me why?

$L = \{ \langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)|\geq 17 \}$

Comment: Rice's theorem is a general theorem to know if some languages are recursive or not. It is not necessary to use it in my answer, just to have some insight on languages (and it does not say anything about RE languages). For your new language, see [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science))

Comment: Okay thank you, but I don't understand why this language is NOT-RE 
$L = \{ \langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)| \neq 17 \}$ because it looks very very similar with this language
$L = \{ \langle M\rangle \mid |L(M)| \geq 17 \}$
and we can use exactly same reduction.

Comment: For $|L(M)|\geqslant 17$, once you have found at least $17$ inputs, you are done, and don't have anything to verify. For $|L(M)| \neq 17$, either you will not find $17$ inputs, and have to continue testing new inputs, or you find $17$ inputs, and have to verify all the other to be sure that none are in the language. In both case, your algorithm may not terminate.

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, this is a great answer, hopefully you can help edit the question (title and body) a bit so that this question is more useful and able to properly introduce the answer. There is a relevant badge, lifejacket.